# No result after calculating the similarity of two words based on word vectors via Spacy's parser?

Tags: parsing, nlp, spacy

I have an example in spacy code:

```
    from numpy import dot
    from numpy.linalg import norm
    from spacy.lang.en import English

    parser = English()
    # you can access known words from the parser's vocabulary
    nasa = parser.vocab[u'NASA']

    # cosine similarity
    cosine = lambda v1, v2: dot(v1, v2) / (norm(v1) * norm(v2))

    # gather all known words, take only the lowercased versions
    allWords = list({w for w in parser.vocab if w.has_vector and 
    w.orth_.islower() and w.lower_ != unicode("nasa")})

    # sort by similarity to NASA
    allWords.sort(key=lambda w: cosine(w.vector, nasa.vector))
    allWords.reverse()
    print("Top 10 most similar words to NASA:")
    for word in allWords[:10]:
         print(word.orth_)
```

The result is like this:

```
    Top 10 most similar words to NASA:

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

So there is no similar words come out.
I have tried to install the parser and glove via cmd:

```
    python -m spacy.en.download parser
    python -m spacy.en.download glove
```

But failed, it turned out to be:

```
    C:\Python\python.exe: No module named en
```

By the way, I use:

```
    Python 2.7.9
    Spacy  2.0.9
```

What's wrong with it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser you are instantiating contains no word vectors. Check https://spacy.io/models/ for an overview of models.

Comment: Thank you, but I have already install en ('python -m spacy download en') and all available models, but it still doesn't work. Could you  please be more specific?thank you.

Comment: Try the following:

    import spacy
    parser = spacy.load('en_vectors_web_lg')

Comment: sorry to bother you, but when running this, I get RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in float_scalars
  cosine = lambda v1, v2: dot(v1, v2) / (norm(v1) * norm(v2)). And the result is weird.           Top 10 most similar words to apple:
fornaro
privatization-consulting
crocodile-hunting
jiangxin
polacolor
tig
joice
harcourt
sketchers
english-speakers      Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The warning you get means that at some point you're attempting a zero division, which most likely means that some of the vectors are zeros. One way to counter this would be to add a zero-sum check in your list comprehension. Another way to solve this would be to call numpy's nan_to_num to convert nans to zeros in your cosine function. As for the weird results, I'm not sure what might be the cause- are the similarities of these words to nasa nans?

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a try.  As for the results, I change the word from "NASA" to "apple", then the exactly same results come out. Maybe the reason is the "zero division", I'm not sure.

Comment: After solving the "zero division" problem, the results now make sense, thank you!